# Replace all character between someWords in all occurrence

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

**Replace all character between "b" and "g" in JAVA**

I have a string like (**Input**)

```
String s="abcdefghabcdefghij";
```

I need output like (**Output**)

```
ab*ghab**ghij
```

Comment: Just to be sure, those '**' were a typo?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
String st = s.replace("cdef", "*");
```

then use the new string

Or you can keep the old variable with the new value

```
s = s.replace("cdef", "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace every thing between b and g you can just use :

```
String s = "abcdefghabcdefghij";
s = s.replaceAll("(.*b)(.*?)(g.*)", "$1*$2");//output = ab*ghab*cdef
```

But the output is not match your's, instead, You can use Pattern to solve your problem :

```
String s = "abcdefghabcdefghij";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("b(.*?)g");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
int i = 1;
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group(1);//match every thing between b and g
    //create n (*) based on the number of Iteration, the 1st only one star the second 2 ..
    //and use replaceFirst to replace the first matches
    s = s.replaceFirst(group, String.format("%0" + i++ + "d", 0).replace("0", "*"));
}
System.out.println(s);// output ab*ghab**ghij
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("b(.*?)g");
String[] arr = { "abcdefghabcdefghij" };
for (String str : arr) {
    String s = p.matcher(str).replaceAll("b*g");
    System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", str, s);
}
```

I am assuming ** is typo error, if not so then use some counter to put desired number of *.

Answer (score 0):

Like @sanit I'm assuming the ** is a typo, and the asterisk count isn't incremented depending on the number of replacements:

- Option 1: "bg" is hard-coded into the replacement string

  ```
  String string = "abcdefghabcdefghij";
  string = string.replaceAll("b.*?g", "b*g");
  System.out.println(string);
  ```
- Option 2: A bit more flexible. "bg" isn't hard-coded:

  ```
  String string = "abcdefghabcdefghij";
  while (string.matches("b.*?g")) {
      String curMatch = string.substring(string.indexOf("b") + 1, string.indexOf("g"));                                               
      string = string.replaceFirst(curMatch, "*");
  }
  ```